# Alternate proof of Vizing's Theorem

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, reference-request

I am doing a bit of research involving graph edge coloring and I was wondering if anyone knows of an alternate proof of Vizing's Theorem. A link to a source is specifically what I am looking for.

I consider the main proof to be the "shifting fan" argument, as seen here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vizing%27s_theorem

Essentially, one takes an uncolored and edge and constructs a sequence of neighbors of one of its endpoints that allow for the colors of some edges to be shifted around. Then, this shifting is used to make room to color an additional edge.

I have looked at many sources and all of them have more or less used the exact same proof. I believe this was the original proof that Vizing himself gave. Does anyone know of any different techniques?

Answer (score 1):

I have to study both proofs more closely to say for sure, but I feel that this one is really different from the one on Wikipedia (e.g. using induction on the number of colors and the number of vertices, rather than on the number of edges): https://homepages.cwi.nl/~lex/files/vizing.pdf